# Deleting a certain amount of variables(not all not one) with one command in bash scripting

Tags: bash, variables

if I create 9 variables `programming=good` `l=20` and `value=56` ...etc and etc and if try of deleting a certain amount of variables then comes the problem I already know the command line `unset` but it will consume more time if I tried to delete each one of them so, I need a command line of deleting a certain amount of variables to reduce consumption of time in bash scripting

Comment: Can you explain what your desired input/output is here?  You want to create 9 variables, remove some and then ... I'm lost.

Comment: @Nathan Champion  I created a few programs in my terminal and then I wanted to delete a few without closing the terminal then i started using the `unset`command but then it was time-consuming so i asked if there was a command where i could minimize the time so do you know any other command for deleting instead of `unset`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see how deleting shell variables would in a noticeable way affect the time a script takes to execute, but `unset` takes more than one argument:

```
unset x y z
```

removes all three variables.